# Symfony profiler logging only exceptions

Tags: php, symfony, profiler

I'd like to set the Symfony 4 profiler to log only exceptions. The application works in dev environment. Having default config everything works as expected - the profiler logs each request (including exceptions).

I found a setting concerning resolving my case: `only_exceptions` and according to the documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#only-exceptions), this should do the trick. But it doesn't, after changing this to `true`, the profiler logs entirely nothing, even though I deliberately throw an exception.

My `config/packages/dev/web_profiler.yaml`:

```
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

framework:
    profiler: { only_exceptions: true }
```

I've tried this setting for both Symfony versions (3 & 4), in neither of them it seems to work. Is there anybody able to help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello, did you tried to use `collect: false` flag also with `only_exception` flag?

Comment: Thanks for the hint but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Also, try to "activate the data collectors manually" with `enabled:              true` flag - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#collect

Comment: And also there a bit another format for this flags - https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#full-default-configuration

Comment: Are you asking for log records? "var/log/dev.log"